# Send Mail using PL/SQL without SMTP

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any other way to send email from Oracle except using SMTP :

Kindly let me know if there is any way with some example if possible.

Comment: Do you mean avoiding the UTL_SMTP package; or not using the SMTP protocol or an SMTP server?

Comment: Hey Alex.. not using SMTP server

Comment: An alternative is to use a mail gateway that offers a REST-style API, like Mailgun. I've been working on a PL/SQL API for Mailgun which you may be interested in: https://github.com/jeffreykemp/mailgun-plsql-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Starting from Oracle 8i release 8.1.6, one can send E-mail messages directly from PL/SQL using either the UTL_TCP or UTL_SMTP packages.](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL)

**Send mail with UTL_TCP**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SEND_MAIL (
  msg_from    varchar2 := 'oracle',
  msg_to      varchar2,
  msg_subject varchar2 := 'E-Mail message from your database',
  msg_text    varchar2 :=  )
IS
  c  utl_tcp.connection;
  rc integer;
BEGIN
  c := utl_tcp.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 25);       -- open the SMTP port 25 on local machine
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(c, TRUE));
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'HELO localhost');
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(c, TRUE));
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'MAIL FROM: '||msg_from);
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(c, TRUE));
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'RCPT TO: '||msg_to);
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(c, TRUE));
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'DATA');                 -- Start message body
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(c, TRUE));
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'Subject: '||msg_subject);
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, );
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, msg_text);
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, '.');                    -- End of message body
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(c, TRUE));
  rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'QUIT');
  dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(c, TRUE));
  utl_tcp.close_connection(c);                         -- Close the connection
END;
/

-- Test it:
set serveroutput on

exec send_mail(msg_to  =>'you@yourdomain.com');

exec send_mail(msg_to  =>'you@yourdomain.com',  -
           msg_text=>'Look Ma, I can send mail from plsql' -
              );
```

Comment: Thank you !! for your help , but do we need to enable any set up in the environment to make it work, Coz the SMTP is disabled or not installed in our test environment. Kindly help

Comment: you need check status of port 25
https://www.siteground.com/kb/smtp_port_25_blocked/